# facebook sdk 3.8 lint errors when exporting signed application

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

My app works fine when not exporting signed application. However, it starts getting lint problem when exporting signed application. I don't think modifying facebook source code is a good idea, but does anyone know why I get the lint errors below?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that FacebookFragment class should a have a public default constructor and there isn't in FacebookFragment.

They should have probably added:

```
class FacebookFragment extends Fragment{
   public FacebookFragment(){}
}
```

I suggest you simply disable lint from aborting your export.
You can disable it in Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking and uncheck "Run full error..."

Comment: Disabling the lint error checking would work. I try not to do that because I might miss other issue later. I will accept the answer if there is no better solution.

Comment: Perhaps, you can just disable this error type. In the same location there are the different lint errors that you can disable or at least lower their severity.